# Book With Talmudic Moral Proverbs Compilation

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation

is there a book with a compilation of all the moral proverbs found in the Talmud? Not directly related to הלכה (Halacha). For example:

> פסיעה גסה נוטלת אחד מחמש מאות ממאור עיניו של אדם
> A large step takes away one five-hundredth of a person’s eyesight. [(Shabbat 113b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.113b.2?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Some of them might be translated to actual הלכות (Halacha), but in any case I a looking to something have a certain "moral" (מידות) inclination.

Comment: Shavua Tov! Great question! This is not a book, as per your request. But it is a compilation of all the proverbs: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4149131/jewish/21-Talmud-Quotes-About-Human-Nature.htm

Comment: https://mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D/

Comment: @kouty Thanks It seams more or less what I am looking for though not focused on "morals"
 אבל. אזל מן המלאי רבל :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes a book does exist - There is an English sefer entitled *[The Wit and Wisdom of the Talmud](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KBD5PG)* by [Rabbi Reuven Bulka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuven_Bulka) which contains a collection of sayings from Chazal to do with daily living and the like.

Comment: last edition was in 1976. Going to buy a used one

Comment: Cool! I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

[Sefer Michlol Hamaamarim Vehapitgamim](https://mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D/) edited by Mosad HaRav Kook. This book contains almost all sentences and proverbs.

Answer (score 0):

In the back of this Aramaic dictionary there  are a few pages that contain such proverbs from the Talmud.

[image]

These two also have such sayings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [anthology](https://korenpub.com/collections/rabbi-adin-even-israel-steinsaltz/products/a-concise-guide-to-the-sages) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent set of seforim on chumash called עבד המלך which explains may of these mitzvos relating to the parsha.

Comment: Welcome, Ben to MY and thanks for your first answer. I don't know the sefer עבד המלך but from the descriptions, it is not clear to me how it deals with the Talmudic Moral Proverbs that are the subject of the question. Can you please explain by editing the answer?

Answer (score -1):

ספר המידות
Sefer ha-Midot

https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Sefer_Hamidot

https://breslovbooks.com/pdf/hebrew-sefer-hamedos.pdf

https://breslovbooks.com/pdf/hebrew-sefer-hamedos-with-sources-version-2.pdf

......

Comment: Not what the op is looking for